# Dispay html textbox with value from code behind using c#

Tags: c#, html

How can I display an html textbox with value obtained from code behinh?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Asp-Control/HTMLButtonSelectandInputBoxincodebehindC.htm

Answer (score 1):

As long as your string value is not private, you should be able to do something like this

```
<input type="text" value="<%= YourStringValue %>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an actual `<asp:Textbox />` and set it's "text" value directly from the code behind.  If you want to directly inject text into a "normal" html textbox (or anywhere else for that matter), you can use `<%= SomeValue %>`.  Yet another way is to include the `"runat=server"` attribute on standard html elements, allowing you to manipulate them from the codebehind.

Normally I'd just go for the built-in ASP textbox control so I don't have to worry about persisting values/wiring up viewstate/etc.  Injecting dynamic content into plain html elements tends to be an edge case requirement...

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //assign text value here
        txt1.Value = "hello world!";
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="txt1" runat="server" type="text" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```